# ElasticSearch content ACL Filtering performance

Tags: elasticsearch, acl

Following is my content model.

Document(s) are associated with user & group acls defining the principals who have access to the document. 
The document itself is a bunch of metadata & a large content body (extracted from pdfs/docs etc).

The user performing the search has to be limited to only the set of documents he/she is entitled to (as defined by the acls on the document). He/She could have access to the document owing to user acls or owing to the group the user belongs to. 
Both group membership and acls on the document are highly transient in nature meaning a user's group membership changes quite often so are the ACLs  on the document itself.

**Approach 1**
Store the acls on the document along with its metadata as a non-stored field. Expand the groups in the ACL to the individual users (since the acl can be a group).
At the time of query, append a filter to the user query which will do a bool filter to include only documents with the userid in the acl field

```
"filter" : {
        "query" : {
            "term": {
                "acls": "1234"
            }
        }
      }
```

The problem i see with this approach is that documents need to get re-indexed though the document metadata/content is not changed.

Every time a user's group membership changes
Every time the ACL on the document changes (permission changed for the document)

I am assuming that this will lead to a large number of segment creation and merges and especially since the document body (one of the fields of the document) is a pretty large text section.

Approach 2:
This is a modification on the approach 1. This approach attempts to limit the updates on the document when the updates are strictly acl related.

Instead of having the acls defined on the metadata. This approach entails creating multiple types

In the **Document** Index

```
Document (with metadata & text body) as a parent

id
text


userschild Document (parent id & user acls only). This document will exist for each parent

id
parentid
useracls



groupschild Document (parent id & group acls only). This document will exist for each parent with group acls

id
parentid
groupacls
```

In the **Users** Index
An entry for each user in the system with the groups he/she is associated with

```
User
   id
   groups
```

The idea here is that updates are now localized to the different ElasticSearch entities. 
In case of user acl changes only the userschild document will get updated (avoiding a potentially costly update on the parent document).
In case of the group acl changes only the groupschild document will get updated (again avoiding a potentially costly update on the parent document).
In case of user group membership changes again only the secondary index will get updated (avoiding the update on the parent document).

The query itself will look as follows.

```
   "filter" : {
            "query" : {
               "bool": {
                 "should": [
                   {
                      "has_child": {
                        "type": "userschild",
                        "query": {
                          "term": {
                            "users": "1234"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },{
                      "has_child": {
                        "type": "groupschild",
                        "query": {
                        "terms" : {
                          "groups" : {
                            "index" : "users",
                            "type" : "user",
                            "id" : "1234",
                            "path" : "groups"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                      }
                    }
                 ]
               }
            }
          }
```

I have doubts with regards to its scalability owing to the nature of the query that will be involved. It involves two terms query one of which that has to be built from a separate index. I am considering improving the terms lookup using fields with docvalues enabled.

Will the approach 2 scale? The concerns I have are around the has_child query and its scalability.

Could someone clarify my understanding in this regard?

Comment: If your client/application knows the user_id, does it also know which groups a searcher belongs to?  Given searcher's user_id and groups, why not just filter on `matching group ACL` OR `matching user ACL`?

Comment: The reason is that a user could belong to a 1000 groups to 10000 groups, which would make group evaluation a botleneck during queries and has been the problem

Comment: Make sure you read [Practical Considerations for Parent-Child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-performance.html).  There are performance and memory considerations (therefore horizontal scalability limitations) involved.  Do you absolutely have to manage your ACLs in Elastic?  Or can you manage them outside and refer to the major groups (and individual users) on the document directly?

Comment: Storing the acls will allow filtering the docs whilst performing query (instead of post filtering) &  keep faceting and page count intact. In our system the ACL that gets applied could be a user/group or both. I have read the Parent-child documentation. Our use case indicates that number of parent to child ratio will be 1 to 1 or  each parent might have 2 children if we split the acls as group-child & user-child. The high volume of acl update is the reason we want to separate out the acl update to the child document and to avoid reindexing of the whole document everytime only acl changes

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps this is overcomplicated by expanding groups before querying.  How about leaving group identifiers intact in the documents index instead?

Typically, I'd represent this in two indices (no parent-child, or any sort of nested relationships at all).

---

**Users Index**
(sample doc)

```
{
  "user_id": 12345,
  "user_name": "Swami PR"
  "user_group_ids": [900, 901, 902]
}
```

**Document Index**
(sample doc)

```
{
  "doc_id": 98765,
  "doc_name": "Lunch Order for Tuesday - Top Secret and Confidential",
  "doc_acl_read_users": [12345, 12346, 12347],
  "doc_acl_write_users": [12345],
  "doc_acl_read_groups": [435, 620],
  "doc_acl_write_groups": []
}
```

---

That **Users Index** could just as easily be in a database... your app just needs "Swami's" `user_id` and `group_ids` available when querying for documents.

Then, when you query `[Top Secret]` documents as `Swami PR`, (to read), make sure to add:

```
"should": [
  {
    "term": { 
      "doc_acl_read_users": 12345
    }
  },
  {
    "terms": {
      "doc_acl_read_groups": [900, 901, 902]
    }
  },
  "minimum_should_match": 1
]
```

---

I can see 2 main types of updates that can happen here:

1. Users or Groups updated on Document := reindex one record in **Document Index**
2. User added to/removed from Group := reindex one record in **User Index**

With an edge-case

3. User or Group deleted

> okay, here you might want to batch through and reindex all documents
>   periodically to clean out stale user/group identifiers... but
>   theoretically, stale user/group identifiers won't exist in the
>   application anymore, so don't cause issues in the index.

Comment: The problem we observed when we bench marked the approach you just mentioned, scales badly once the number of groups exceeds 1000 on the termlist. Scaling takes a huge hit once we are at around 1000 groups in the terms list. Also to note would be that using a terms query with terms list built externally scales worse than termslist built from the index itself

Comment: Our docs are namely pdfs,docs (size 3MB ..25MB) So adding acls on the primary doc will cause them to be reindexed everytime for acl updates(upto 100,000 updates/hr spanning across many 100,000s of documents). That is the reason for taking the child document acl approach to avoid reindexing the primary doc.

Comment: How many groups does a typical user belong to?  1000s?  And groups are changed on documents 100,000x/hr?

Comment: What % of users belong to >1000 groups?  What % of documents have their group ACLs change any given hour?  If small, do you need to optimize the entire system for them?  If large, then wouldn't it be worth the extra implementation effort of having something like Redis to postfilter with?  (I'm also guessing that much of this traffic is generated by direct User->Doc ACL abuse... Maybe just forcing a groups-only ACL policy will quell the index thrashing)

Comment: There is unfortunately no way to quell the User->Doc ACL abuse since it gets used by customers (10000s) of them. The % of users belonging to 1000 groups is in the few 1000s as opposed to the total subset of the users (several 100k). But these users perform a lot of operations with regards to operations (they are sort of mini admins across one/several containers of documents)

Answer (score -1):

i have implemented the approach #2 in my company, now i'm researching  a graph DB to handle ACL. Once we have crossed 4 million documents for one our clients the updates and search queries became quite frequent and didn't scale as expected.
my suggestion to look into graph frameworks to solve this.